# Swift - Replace Character in String

Tags: variables, replace, character, swift, symbols

I have variable which contents the symbol or character I don't know how you say on this "\" in english... How to replace all \ with empty space in my variable ?

```
var content = theContent["content"] as String
self.contentLabel.text = content.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(<#target: String#>, withString: <#String#>, options: <#NSStringCompareOptions#>, range: <#Range<String.Index>?#>)
```

How to fill this spaces or my sintax is wrong when I use content.string... and then in #target I use the same string ? Anyone who learned Swift so fast? :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the following

```
self.contentLabel.text = content.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to write this in *pure* Swift, try:

```
self.contentLabel.text = Array(myString).reduce("") { $1 == "\\" ? $0 : "\($0)\($1)" }
```

This is a short hand way of writing:

```
Array(myString).reduce("", combine: { (inputString, character) -> String in
    if character == "\\" {
        return inputString
    } else {
        return "\(inputString)\(character)"
    }
})
```

This converts `myString` to an `Array` of `Character`s, then uses the `reduce` function to append them back together into a `String`, but substituting an empty string in place of backslashes

Comment: What do you mean pure swift? This looks intense. Can you explain whats going on in this example?

Comment: By *pure* Swift, I mean that it doesn't use any Foundation classes (NSString, for example) - updated my answer for clarity